# Zend_mail success message comes but mail not send

Tags: php, email, zend-mail

guys i have using a script to send mails, all seems fine with it and even i get the success message but sadly the emails are not delivered.. can any body look for any lapses in this code

Code

```
$body = "This is testmail please ignore";
$mail = new Zend_Mail ();
$tr = new Zend_Mail_Transport_Sendmail ( '-f' . $sentFromEmail );
Zend_Mail::setDefaultTransport ( $tr );
$mail->setReturnPath("user@admin.com");
$mail->setFrom ( "user@admin.com", 'Reporters' );
$mail->setBodyHtml ( $body );
$mail->addTo ( "samjam@gmail.com"  );
$mail->setSubject ( "Weekly Report" );
try {
    $mail->send ();
    echo "Success";
} catch ( Exception $e ) {
    echo "Mail sending failed.\n";
}
```

SMTP configuration

```
 if (isset($config['ssl'])) {
            switch (strtolower($config['ssl'])) {
                case 'tls':
                    $this->_secure = 'tls';
                    break;

                case 'ssl':
                    $this->_transport = 'ssl';
                    $this->_secure = 'ssl';
                    if ($port == null) {
                        $port = 465;
                    }
                    break;

            }
        }


        if ($port == null) {
            if (($port = ini_get('smtp_port')) == '') {
                $port = 25;
            }
        }
```

Comment: show us your SMTP parameters... also check your sent mails in your spam folder

Comment: i chked the spam but no luck... wait ill put the smtp stuff

Comment: Zend tells you the mail was successfully delivered to `sendmail` check your sendmail logs for to see why `sendmail` is not delivering your mail.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is that samjam@gmail.com is not an email address of any email account that you have access to.

It belongs to a private individual who you do not know.

This is the correct answer.